# Android 4.2.2 root certificates SHA-1

Tags: android, security, certificate, sha1

Android Jellybean uses ca root certificates. Those certificates naming are MD5 hash based on Certificate Subject. I would like to change that so that it uses SHA-1 instead of MD5. My doubt is that apparently Apache harmony (what Android uses), generates a different SHA-1 hash than openssl. 
Is Android SHA-1 implementation broken?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks that openssl is not following the same convention for SHA1 as for MD5.
When calculating -subject_hash (SHA1 based on DN of the certificate), openssl first calculates the CANONICAL representation of the DN, then generates de ASN1. DER format based on the CANONICAL format, and then it passes the result to the SHA1 algorithm.

You will have to modify Apache Harmony code to achieve the same results as in openssl